# How to solve “Warning: World-writable config file ‘/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf’ is ignored” in xampp

Tags: php, xampp

How to stop the below warning in xampp?

> Warning: World-writable config file ‘/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf’ is ignored

Comment: Please respect the question-answer format of SO. It's perfectly OK to answer your own question, but do so by formulating the question as a question, and the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 36):

With the stopped server perform:

1. `chmod 644 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`
2. restart the server

Comment: I will also execute command: *chown mysql.mysql /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf*

Comment: chmod 700 /home/ubuntu/my.cnf is worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Hae I Got this error

Warning: World-writable config file '/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf' is ignoredWarning: World-writable config file '/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf' is ignoredWarning: World-writable config file '/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf' is ignored

This is how I solved it hope It work for you

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this Error By the Below Commands :-

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
```

After That Do the 2nd Command:-

```
sudo chmod 600 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
```

Then restart the server.

It Resolve Me. Anyone face this problem try once with above cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but different problem in the end:

changing the permission was not enough, there was something else:

when validating the content of the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` i get this:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

valid that all the files exist and the first file/directory is missing, it occurred to me to proceed to comment it like this:

```
#!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

apply the procedure again with `644` permissions and restart the server, and everything works fine now with no warnings.

[I can't properly set permissions to MySQL config files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/317469/i-cant-properly-set-permissions-to-mysql-config-files)